# Connect to Socket with IPAddress.Any

Tags: sockets, network-programming, ip-address

hej Hej, 
My Question is related to my previous post: 
[Get right ip adress of pc with multiple network cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143346/get-right-ip-adress-of-pc-with-multiple-network-cards)

I changed my code to this:

```
TextFileTracer.Write(String.Format("Create endpoint for host {0}:{1}", MultipleNetworkMod.BindToMultipleNetworks(hostEntry.AddressList(0)).ToString(), _port), TextFileTracer.TraceSource.Framework)
            Dim ep As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port)
            TextFileTracer.Write("Creating socket...", TextFileTracer.TraceSource.Framework)
            s = New Sockets.Socket(ep.AddressFamily, Sockets.SocketType.Stream, Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
            s.Blocking = True
            TextFileTracer.Write("Connecting to endpoint...", TextFileTracer.TraceSource.Framework)
            s.Connect(ep)
            TextFileTracer.Write("Socket connected!", TextFileTracer.TraceSource.Framework)
```

But when connecting tot he Socket I got the exception: 
the requested address is not valid in its context 0.0.0.0: "MyPortNr" (not a string just an int number)

Before we created an IPEndpoint with the first ipaddress from the hostEntry list but beceause of multiple network cards that does not work.

Can someone help me and put me on the right track again?

Greetz,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, see my other thread.
I let the user decide on what networkinterface card to bind, then I determined the IPAddress from this Card.